# Permanent generation heap in DVM

Tags: android, heap-memory, permanent-generation, dvm

Does DVM has same heap structure as JVM has? Does it have Permanent Gen. heap where all the Classes, info. related to that classes(e.g. class name, object array associated to that class, internal class descriptor), static member variables are stored in Permanent Gen. area? If not, how they stored?